# Inserting form values in multiple row using php empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help. I have the following code. I wish that when all fields are not completed, not to introduce the empty fields in the database. Just upload the completed them.

```
for($i = 0; $i <count($_POST)+3; $i++){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `predare`(`id_factura`,`id_student`, `id_produs`, `cantitate`) 
    VALUES('".$_POST['id_factura'][$i]."','".$_POST['id_student'][$i]."', '".$_POST['id_produs'][$i]."', '".$_POST['cantitate'][$i]."');");
}

<input class="input-1" name="cantitate[]" id="cantitate" value="">
<input class="input-1" name="id_factura[]" id="id_factura" value="">
<input class="input-1" name="id_student[]" id="id_student" value="">
<input class="input-1" name="id_produs[]" id="id_produs" value="">
```

Comment: It looks like your form submits values for multiple records. Do you mean that you only want to INSERT as many records as there are sets of $_POST values?

Comment: Yes. Only records. Empty fields not.

Comment: OK. Would you want to insert rows where only some of the values of were given, or complete rows only?

Comment: I want to INSERT in database only rows with some of the values or all the rows completed.

Comment: It is never a good idea to execute a query inside a loop. And please stop using this long-since deprecated API. use PDO/mysqli_ AND prepared statements!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would suggest doing it. First initialize your SQL string and a separator (for inserting multiple records with one query.)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `predare` (`id_factura`,`id_student`, `id_produs`, `cantitate`) VALUES ";
$separator = '';
```

Then loop over the submitted rows and append to the SQL string if the rows have all four values.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cantitate']); $i++) {
    $values = array(); 
    foreach (array('id_factura', 'id_student', 'id_produs', 'cantitate') as $column) {
        // only add values to the $values array if something has been entered
        // (empty fields will be present as '', which evaluates to false)
        if ($_POST[$column][$i]) $values[] = $_POST[$column][$i];
    }
    if (count($values) == 4) { // only add the values to the SQL if all fields are present
        $sql .= "$separator ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')";
        $separator = ',';
    }
}
```

Then you can execute the SQL statement to insert all the complete records at once.

If you wanted to include incomplete (but not empty) rows, you could use 
`if ($values) {...` instead of `if (count($values) == 4) {...`

One benefit to setting it up this way is that it would be easier to convert the code to use a better database extension (such as PDO) with prepared statements instead of concatenating the values into the SQL like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the $_POST['id_factura'] array and You need to check the values before the insert statement like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i <count($_POST['id_factura']); $i++){
   if(isset($_POST['id_factura'][$i]) && isset($_POST['id_student'][$i]) && isset($_POST['id_produs'][$i]) && isset($_POST['cantitate'][$i])){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `predare`(`id_factura`,`id_student`, `id_produs`, `cantitate`) 
    VALUES('".$_POST['id_factura'][$i]."','".$_POST['id_student'][$i]."', '".$_POST['id_produs'][$i]."', '".$_POST['cantitate'][$i]."');");
    }
}
```

Or you can check if the integer values are greater then 0...